# Mi Cookie no se actualiza PHP

Tags: php

Partiendo de la base que está creada una cookie llamada lista, con el valor "-".

Intento que conforme se vayan entrando en los productos de una página se vaya añadiendo contenido a la cookie. Pero no me actualiza:

Este es el código:

```
 if(isset($_COOKIE["lista"])) {
        $var = $_COOKIE["lista"] . "-" . $id;
        setcookie("lista", $var, time() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60, "/");
    } else {
        $var = "-";
        setcookie("lista", $var, time() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60, "/");
    }
```

La cookie "lista" siempre es "-"

EDITO: He borrado la cookie, para ver que hace el código en caso de que no exista la cookie, pero no se crea, según el código al no existir la cooie "lista" tendria que crearla con el valor "-", pero no la creo

EDITO: Estoy viendo que me tira este error:

:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/2019/includes/menu.php:64) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/2019/alquiler.php  on line 52.

No se porqué me dice eso, todo esto lo ejecuto antes del doctype

EDITO:
´´´

```
if(isset($_GET["material"])) {
    $urlamigable = $_GET["material"];
} else {
    ?>
    <script>window.location="alquileres.php";</script>
    <?php
}

$id     = NULL;
$titulo = NULL;
$precio = NULL;
$imagen = NULL;
$descripcion = NULL;

$rel_titulo = NULL;
$rel_thumb = NULL;
$rel_descripcion = NULL;


$sql = "SELECT * FROM materiales WHERE urlamigable = '$urlamigable'";
if($resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id     = $fila["idmaterial"];
        $titulo = $fila["titulo"];
        $precio = $fila["precio"];
        $imagen = $fila["imagen"];
        $descripcion = $fila["descripcion"];
    }
    $resultado->free();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM material ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";
if($resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rel_titulo = $fila["titulo"];
        $rel_imagen = $fila["imagen"];
        $rel_descripcion = $fila["descripcion"];
    }
    $resultado->free();
}

if(isset($_COOKIE["lista"])) {
    $var = $_COOKIE["lista"] . "-" . $id;
    setcookie("lista", $var, time() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60, "/");
} else {
    $var = "-";
    setcookie("lista", $var, time() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60, "/");
}

  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
Y luego el resto de la página
```

```
SOLUCIONADO: tenía unos include y en esos archivos si habían "echo" antes de doctype
```

Comment: Estas seguro que tu cookie esta disponible en todas las paginas, creo que a lo mejor te falta el parametro "/" para que este disponible en todas las paginas.
setcookie("lista", $var, time() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60,"/");

Comment: Aun añadiendo "/" sigue sin aparecer, no se crea la cookie

Comment: @scorpio408 He editado el hilo con un error que me salta

Comment: El error que comentas es porque en el php estás generando algo en la salida antes de poner alguna cabecera. Debes tener un echo o print antes del doctype. Pon el código entero si no encuentras el fallo. PD:No me deja comentar por no tener la suficiente reputación.

Comment: Te refieres a que no tengo que tener ningun echo o print antes del doctype o despues ?

Comment: Hola el el siguiente link es descrita la problemática y solución: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658093/7898235 ; básicamente es por que cualquier declaración de setcookie debe ser antes de cualquier HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tienes que tener ningún echo o print antes del doctype.

Comment: si ves el codigo que tengo, no tengo ninguno antes del doctype, pero sigue saltando

Comment: pero tienes esto que se escribe en el else, eso se escribe en el documento antes que el doctype <script>window.location="alquileres.php";</script>

Vale es una redirección, usa la redirección de php mejor, no? 
header("Location: alquileres.php");

Comment: Eso no entraba en conflicto. Era que tenia unos echo, en un archivo que lo incluia con include

Comment: Ya lo he visto. 
Yo haría la redirección con php. Tal y como la tienes tu documento se envía al cliente y es el cliente el que pide la redirección. Si haces la redirección con php te evitas ese paso y será el php el que redirija directamente ahorrando tiempo y tráfico.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando creas la cookie en el else estás multiplicando time() por los segundos de un año y lo que debes de hacer es sumar los segundos de un año. En el if lo tienes bien.

```
 if(isset($_COOKIE["lista"])) {
    $var = $_COOKIE["lista"] . "-" . $id;
    setcookie("lista", $var, time() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
} else {
    $var = "-";
    setcookie("lista", $var, time() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
}
```

Al crear la cookie en el else como multiplicas time() por los segundos del año te estás saliendo del rango, estás poniendo que expire en un año mayor que 9999 y eso da error.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, edité el código con lo que tengo, pero no crea la cookie.

Comment: He editado el hilo con un error que me salta